# Proving conditional independence

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

I have the following problem:

Three random variables have the following joint distribution:

$$
P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)P(Y|X)P(Z|Y)
$$

Show that $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$.

The solution that I have been given is:

$$
P(X)P(Y|X)P(Z|Y) = \frac{P(X)P(Y|X)P(Z|Y)}{P(Y)} = \frac{P(X,Y)}{P(Y)}P(Z|Y) = P(X|Y)P(Z|Y)
$$

But no explanation was given for how each of these steps where reached - is anyone able to elaborate on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathcal P}}$
The solution should be

$$\begin{align}\because \P(X,Y,Z) & = \P(X)\P(Y\mid X)\P(Z\mid Y) \\ \P(X, Z\mid Y) & = \frac{\P(X,Y,Z)}{\P(Y)} \\ & =\frac{\P(X)\P(Y\mid X)\P(Z\mid Y)}{\P(Y)} \\ & = \frac{\P(X)\P(Y\mid X)}{\P(Y)}\P(Z\mid Y) \\ & = \P(X\mid Y)\P(Z\mid Y) \\ \therefore X\bot Z \mid Y\end{align}$$

---

You have been given: $$\because \P(X,Y,Z) = \P(X)\P(Y\mid X)\P(Z\mid Y) \tag{1}$$

Now, by definition of conditional probability: $$\P(X,Z\mid Y) = \dfrac{\P (X, Y, Z)}{\P(Y)} \tag{2}$$

By substitution (1) into (2): $$\P(X,Z\mid Y) = \dfrac{\P(X)\P(Y\mid X)\P(Z\mid Y)}{\P(Y)}\tag{3}$$

A trivial rearrangement of (3) shows that: $$\P(X,Z\mid Y) = \dfrac{\P(X)\P(Y\mid X)}{\P(Y)}\P(Z\mid Y) \tag{4}$$

Now, again by definition (or Bayes' rule): $$\dfrac{\P(X)\P(Y\mid X)}{\P(Y)}=\P(X\mid Y) \tag{5}$$

So substitution of (5) into (4) yields: $$\P(X,Z\mid Y)= \P(X\mid Y)\P(Z\mid Y)\tag{6}$$

This is the sufficient and necessary requirement for conditional independence.
 $$\P(X,Z\mid Y)= \P(X\mid Y)\P(Z\mid Y) \iff X \bot Z \mid Y \tag{7}$$

Which was to be shown.
$$\therefore X\bot Z \mid Y \mathbb{\tag{QED}}$$

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Quick question though - how come we can use the definition of conditional independence when this is what we are trying to prove? Does this mean we are working under the assumption that they are conditionally independent from the beginning?

Comment: #rheotron.  Ah, no. Sorry about that typo.  We're using the definition of conditional *probability* and the given equation to demonstrate we have conditional independence.